# Facebook issue with same keystore in two computers

Tags: android, facebook, ionic2, key, ionic3

I have an Ionic 2 app published on Google Play.
I was working on my own, but now we are three programmers in the same app, and we need to be able to sign the apk and upload to Google Play all of us.

The problem is with facebook. When we test the app connected via USB, and we want to do login with facebook, we get this msg:

> "Invalid key hash. The key hash XXXXXX does not match any stored key
>   hashes. Configure your app key hashes at
>   http:developers.faceblablalbalbal"

**But in my pc it works properly.**

So, I copied the keystore file on their pc's and ran `keytool -exportcert -alias android_release_key -keystore release-key.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

But the key hash that we get it's the same that is configured in facebook developers console.

What can we do?

Thank's a lot!

**EDIT:** 
They are able to sign apk and upload it to Google Play with this keystore. The problem is with Facebook login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy your `XXXXXX` from error and add it to Key Hashes (you can add multiple).

Comment: I did it, but the problem persist.

Comment: I was copying wrong keyhash. I was confused between a minuscule "L" and a Latin "i" uppercase, are equal to the view: I (i) l (L)

Comment: Glad to hear that